# error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _H_get0_pqg when using Shining Light Productions

Tags: c, openssl

I am using openssl by [Shining Light Productions](https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html)!. I configured my project correctly and my code can be compiled. when i add another line code:

```
H_get0_pqg(dh1,&p,&q,&g);
```

It is not complied and show some error:

> 1>------ Build started: Project: dh, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
>   1>     Creating library F:\Using_OpenSSL\Release\dh.lib and object F:\Using_OpenSSL\Release\dh.exp
>   1>dh.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _H_get0_pqg
>   1>F:\Using_OpenSSL\Release\dh.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
>   ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

I try some method, such as adding new lib file, but all failed.

> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _H_get0_pqg

The code all in my program is below:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>
#include<openssl\dh.h>
#include<openssl\applink.c>

int main()
{
    DH *dh1, *dh2;

    dh1 = DH_new(); 
    dh2 = DH_new();

    int ret;
    ret = DH_generate_parameters_ex(dh1, 128, DH_GENERATOR_2, NULL);

    printf("generating DH param success!...\n");

    DHparams_print_fp(stdout, dh1); 

    if (ret != 1)
    {
        printf("generating DH param failed!\n");
        goto lab1;
    }

    int err_code;
    ret = DH_check(dh1, &err_code);

    if (ret != 1)
    {
        if (err_code & DH_CHECK_P_NOT_PRIME)
            printf("p is not prime!\n");

        if (err_code & DH_CHECK_P_NOT_SAFE_PRIME)
            printf("p is not safe prime!\n");

        if (err_code & DH_UNABLE_TO_CHECK_GENERATOR)
            printf("is not checking generator's value!\n");

        if (err_code & DH_NOT_SUITABLE_GENERATOR)
            printf("is not generator!\n");

        goto lab1;
    }

    printf("DH param checking...\n");

    int param_len;
    param_len = DH_size(dh1);
    printf("DH param size(byte) %d\n", param_len);
    printf("DH param size(bit) %d\n", DH_bits(dh1));

    ret = DH_generate_key(dh1);
    if (ret != 1) 
    {
        printf("DH_generate_key error!\n");

        goto lab1;
    }

    DHparams_print_fp(stdout, dh1); 

    BIGNUM *p = BN_new();
    BIGNUM *q = BN_new();
    BIGNUM *g = BN_new();

    H_get0_pqg(dh1,&p,&q,&g); 

    DHparams_print_fp(stdout, dh2); 

    BN_free(p);
    BN_free(q);
    BN_free(g);
lab1:
    DH_free(dh1); 
    DH_free(dh2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you have a linker error we need to see your linker settings (i.e. a [mre]) to know what is wrong

Comment: I can't find any function called `H_get0_pqg` in the openssl headers or documentation, it must be coming from somewhere else

Comment: You can find [H_get0_pqg](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/DH_get0_pqg.html).

Comment: I set additional include directories:  _F:\OpenSSL-Win32\include_, additional library directories: _F:\OpenSSL-Win32\lib_, additional dependencies(linker->input): _libcrypto.lib libssl.lib_.

Comment: There is no function called `H_get0_pqg` on the page you linked to